# How do I increase the maximum length of a MySQL error message?

Tags: mysql, triggers, message

I wrote a BEFORE INSERT trigger on a particular table in my database in order to impose some value constraints. The code returns a semicolon-separated list of errors. My intent was to have my flask app then return this list of user-defined error messages to the client.

However, if more than one error occurs, the message gets cut off mid sentence.

Here is the sort of redacted error message:

```
The specified xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx (105) exceeds the maximum value (100).;
The specified xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx (90) is
```

Here is some of the code for the trigger:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE rtn TEXT;
    DECLARE error BOOLEAN;
    -- Declare variables here
    -- Select some values into those variables
    -- Check new row fields against variables
    IF error THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02001'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = rtn;
    END IF;
```

Comment: There is not enough information to help you.  My opinion is that mysql errors should not be occurring.  You should have sorted most issues out.  And what you have not should be logged.  If this are **value errors because of user entry**, then they should be in the user interface not in the database !!!  It is not logical to try and save bad data and rely on the database to respond with errors.

Comment: Why isn't it logical to try to save un-validated data and rely on the database to validate it?

Comment: Please post more of your store procedure code, especially the bits used in your example result.

Comment: @JamalMcTravis, Whatever floats your boat !!  But to me it makes no sense to flush everything down the toilet and rely on a sewer inspector to catch a tin  can and send it back.  It would be better to not to flush the can in the first place.

Comment: I have flagged it for closure because there is not enough information for anyone to duplicate your problem or to help you with it.  Downvotes, if any are not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PHP, there is maximum limit for exception messages.  This is defined by **log_errors_max_len** in php.ini.  Refer here for more details  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31955

You can try and change that.

But I would suggest using a stored procedure/function to insert the data.  It can then return an error value of any length.